# Opening WSP in VS

Tags: migration, solution-package

I am new to sharepoint!. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.I have extracted the wsp file by renaming it to cab. But when I open it as a website in Visual Studio, It does not have master file and CSS files.
Can anyone please explain how to make changes to the wsp file using VS and to build and deploy it.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make changes to a already compiled WSP file. You need to have the Visual Studio Project instead. This Visual Studio Project packages all the assets to a WSP add the compiled dlls and every thing else.

I highly recommend tho read the basic information on the MSDN
[Create SharePoint Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330921.aspx) first.

Comment: I am working on sharepoint migration. So I was given a wsp file. I need to make some modifications to it and I need to deploy it. Please confirm me that renaming wsp to cab, then open in VS, modify based on the change needed, deploy it - these steps would work or not.

Comment: No this steps won't work you need to have an updated WSP for the new SharePoint Version out of the Visual Studio Project.

Comment: It is asking for me to install Sharepoint Server on my machine to create a project.(which I dont have permission). Is there any work around ?.. Kindly advice me !

Comment: No you have to start the Visual Studio on a Server where SharePoint is install. Shouldn't be a productive server. For this you should check the requirements. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231582.aspx

Comment: In the test environment we are able to open the files and make changes to it directly(to make the system work the way we want it to be). My question is why do we need VS to open it. What is the main role of VS.